# "invalid volume specification" when passing environment variables

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Host: Centos 7
Docker version: 19.03.12, build 48a66213fe
Docker compose version: version 1.26.2, build eefe0d31

I am using the advice given [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/) on specifying environment variables in the shell and then passing those into the compose file. So my `docker-compose` file looks like this:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
 springboot:
  image: <my image>
  ports:
   - "8445:8445"
  depends_on:
   - "database"
  environment:
   - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev
 database:
  image: "mongo"
```

Here's the error that I've run into:

```
ERROR: for 39b165c237b9_deploy_springboot_1  Cannot create container for service springboot: invalid volume specification: 'a9d7debde5ffcba2a023c12d5f1e822567e9b4047a1bda76efeefbfc80c1f622:app/data:rw': invalid mount config for type "volume": invalid mount path: 'app/data' mount path must be absolute
```

The corresponding Docker file does have a reference to `VOLUME app/data`, however that doesn't seem controversial.

If I take out the `environment` block, it seems to work fine (though the application starts without having the right config, but at least it doesn't error).

So what is the right way to pass on shell environment variables to the container?

**EDIT**
Thanks to @David Maze, it was indeed the VOLUME declaration in the original Docker file - nothing to do with `docker-compose`. Deleted it and it now works. Thanks!

Comment: That `VOLUME` line probably does cause that error – it instructs Docker to mount an anonymous volume on that directory if nothing else is mounted there.  There's not usually a reason to have this in your Dockerfile and I'd try deleting it.  (The `environment:` you show here seems fine.)

Comment: How are you mounting a volume? There's nothing about it in the docker-compose config you posted.

Comment: @kaveh updated above

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 ways to specify directories in docker.

- absolute path i.e. from the root e.g. /var/lib
- relative path i.e. relative to the compose file e.g. ./app/data

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev`by `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: dev` Instead, so replace `=` with `:` . And you should also add the `volume` to the `docker-compose` file:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
    .
    .
  volumes:
   - Path/to/your/volume
  environment:
   ENV_VAR1: Value1
   ENV_VAR2: Value2
   .
   .
   .
```

And according the error message, the path must be absolute.